# How do you display Ruby ActiveAdmin attributes_table rows in 2 or more columns?

Tags: html, css, activeadmin

With ActiveAdmin, you can have an `attributes_table`, eg

```
show do
    attributes_table do
        row :name
        row :gender
        row :email
        row :phone_number
    end
end
```

You would have a table with a bunch of rows, like the following:

```
Name              Joe Smith
Gender            Male
Email             joe.smith@joesmith.com
Phone Number      07722123456
```

The generated html looks like

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="row row-name">
            <th>Name</th>
            <td>Joe Smith</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row row-name">
            <th>Gender</th>
            <td>Male</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row row-name">
            <th>Email</th>
            <td>joe.smith@joesmith.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row row-name">
            <th>Phone Number</th>
            <td>07722123456</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I would like to display these attributes in 2 columns, like

```
Name      Joe Smith                  Gender         Male
Email     joe.smith@joesmith.com     Phone Number   07722123456
```

How do I achieve this easily with ActiveAdmin?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is an Arbre componenet to help with this, take a look at the documentation at https://activeadmin.info/12-arbre-components.html#columns